# The best practice for IOS and Android notifications - push one by on or an aggregate push?

Tags: android, ios, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push

I am making IOS and android application with IOS native and GCM push notifications. Currently, my server is forwarding request to push server each time. Is this good practice or is it better to aggregate messages (let say in database) and then to push it every x seconds?

Comment: while using apple push I have discovered that you open connection with apple server and send message. if you open connection multiple times this is considered as DoS attack and connection will be refused. So for the IOS answer will be to push at once as many messages as possible and avoid multiple connections

Answer (score 0):

If your server sends multiple messages in short spans of time, sending them separately may negatively affect the battery life of the receiving client devices. Of course, this could be a necessity if your service is of an extremely urgent nature.

If your service can afford to wait/aggregate messages, you may want to consider using GCM collapse keys to limit the amount of message traffic.